# Convert int to hex of a given number of characters

Tags: python, type-conversion, hex

I want to convert my `int` number into an `hex` one specifying the number of characters in my final hex representation.

This is my simple code that takes an input an converts it into `hex`:

```
my_number = int(1234)
hex_version = hex(my_number)
```

This code returns a string equal to `0x4d2`.

However I would like my output to contain 16 characters, so basically it should be `0x00000000000004d2`.

Is there a way to specify the number of output character to the `hex()` operator? So that it pads for the needed amount of 0.

Comment: Use zfill(width) func to fill n number of zeros on left side of ur string

Comment: @Lalitkumar, could you please describe how?

Comment: @anurag read shared link "https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/zfill"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```py
n = int(1234)
h = format(n, '#018x')
```

The above will generate the required string. The magic number 18 is obtained as follows: 16 for the width you need + 2 for '0' (zero) and 'x' (for the hex descriptor string prefix).